# How to add more lines to a plot done with ggplot2 that has double y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

The dataframe `df1` summarizes the mean daily depth (`meanDepth`) of a fish throught time, also the mean daily water temperature to different depths (`T5m`, `T15m`, `T25m` and `T35m`) and the overall mean daily temperature (`meanT`) for the whole water column (without considering different depths). As an example:

```
df1<- data.frame(Date=c("2016-08-05","2016-08-06","2016-08-07","2016-08-08","2016-08-09","2016-08-10"),
                 meanDepth=c(15,22,18,25,27,21),
                 T5m=c(17,18,21,23,21,18),
                 T15m=c(16,17,18,19,18,17),
                 T25m=c(16,17,17,18,18,17),
                 T35m=c(15,16,17,17,17,16),
                 meanT=c(16,17.2,17.8,18.3,17.8,17.4))
df1$Date<-as.Date(df1$Date)

df1

        Date meanDepth T5m T15m T25m T35m meanT
1 2016-08-05        15  17   16   16   15  16.0
2 2016-08-06        22  18   17   17   16  17.2
3 2016-08-07        18  21   18   17   17  17.8
4 2016-08-08        25  23   19   18   17  18.3
5 2016-08-09        27  21   18   18   17  17.8
6 2016-08-10        21  18   17   17   16  17.4
```

I want to plot in one graph both the depth profile of the fish and the mean daily temperature for the different depths.

What I've got so far is to plot in one Y-axis the `meanDepth` and in the other y-axis the `meanT`. But I don't know how to add more lines related to the right-y-axis (=Temperature) that represent the mean daily temperature for different depths. Here you have the code I've been able to built so far.

```
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Date))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = meanDepth, colour = "Overall daily mean depth"))
p <- p + geom_line(aes(y = meanT/(max(range(df1$meanT,na.rm=TRUE)/max(range(df1$meanDepth,na.rm=TRUE)))), colour = "Mean Water T"))
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*(max(range(df1$meanT,na.rm=TRUE)/max(range(df1$meanDepth,na.rm=TRUE)))), name = "Mean daily Temp"))
p <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red"))
p <- p + labs(title="Mean daily depth and water temperature through time",
              y = "Mean daily depth",
              x = "Date",
              colour = "Parameter")
p <- p + theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9), plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold",margin = margin(0,0,12,0) ),axis.title.y =element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 12, b = 0, l = 0)),axis.title.x =element_text(margin = margin(t = 12, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
p <- p + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 days", labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d"))
p
```

That's the plot I've got:
[image]

Does anyone how to add the lines referred to the temperatures at 5, 15, 25 and 35 meters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, it's sufficient to add a `geom_line` for each of the temperatures/columns. Here's an example with `T5m` and `T35m`.

```
df1<- data.frame(Date=c("2016-08-05","2016-08-06","2016-08-07",
                        "2016-08-08","2016-08-09","2016-08-10"),
                 meanDepth=c(15,22,18,25,27,21),
                 T5m=c(17,18,21,23,21,18),
                 T15m=c(16,17,18,19,18,17),
                 T25m=c(16,17,17,18,18,17),
                 T35m=c(15,16,17,17,17,16),
                 meanT=c(16,17.2,17.8,18.3,17.8,17.4))
df1$Date<-as.Date(df1$Date)
norm <- max(df1$meanT,na.rm=TRUE)/max(df1$meanDepth,na.rm=TRUE)
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = meanDepth, colour = "Overall daily mean depth")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = meanT/norm, colour = "Mean Water T")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = T5m/norm, colour = "T5m")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = T35m/norm, colour = "T35m")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 days", labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*norm, name = "Mean daily Temp")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red", "orange", "black")) +
  labs(title="Mean daily depth and water temperature through time",
       y = "Mean daily depth",
       x = "Date",
       colour = "Parameter") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.9),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold", margin = margin(0,0,12,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 12, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 12, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) 
p
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks @Arienrhod, I will check it now. Do you know how to select specific colours for the lines? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You set the colors in the `scale_color_manual`. If you meant how to come up with different colors, check out colorbrewer2.org.

Comment: One last question, I added the lines `geom_line(aes(y = T15m/norm, colour = "T15m"))` and `geom_line(aes(y = T25m/norm, colour = "T25m"))` to include all the lines and I got the message `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 6 needed but only 4 provided`. Can this problem be solved? What I did was just to add those lines among the geom_line for `T5m` and the linge for `T35m`.

Comment: you need to add custom color for every added line to the `scale_color_manual`.

Answer (score 4):

Secondary axes are almost never a good idea, but you could do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(meanDepthNormalized = meanDepth * max(meanT) / max(meanDepth)) %>% #1
  select(-meanDepth) %>% 
  # could have changed meanDepth before directly, but wanted to be more verbose
  gather(type, value, -Date) %>% #2
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = value, color = type, linetype = type == "meanT")) + #3
    geom_line(size = 1.5) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * max(df1$meanDepth) / max(df1$meanT))) +
    scale_color_manual("", values = c("#E41A1C", "#984EA3", "#BDD7E7",
                                      "#6BAED6", "#3182BD", "#08519C")) +
    theme_minimal() + 
    guides(linetype = FALSE) +
    theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image: Dual Axis]

**Explanation**

1. You first transform your Depth to be on the same scale as the temperature measurements
2. Then you transform your data from wide to long format via `gather`
3. Then you can map color to the type variable which holds basically the former column names.

Answer (score 2):

maybe with facet_grid(y ~., scales = "free")

here a example

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
   geom_boxplot() + 
   facet_grid(cyl ~., scales = "free")
```